# jquery ajax method returns null value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have an ajax function like this:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AjaxControls.aspx/CreateUserLevel',
        data: { LevelNameAddLevel: $('#LevelNameAddLevel').val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            if (response == "true")
            {
            $("#ErrorDivAddLevel").html('Level created  successfully!').fadeIn('slow');
             }
            else
             {
                $("#SuccessDivAddLevel").html('Level creation failed!').fadeIn('slow');
             }
         }
});
```

The issue is that the response returned a null value.

The web method is:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=False)>
Public Shared Function CreateUserLevel() As String
    Return "true"
End Function
```

Comment: What is your response?

Comment: How does the response look like on the wire?

Comment: the response i got is 'Null'

Comment: change the data type to `html` and tell use what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should have contentType other wise it doesnt know what its parsing, for example `contentType: "application/json",`
and you should strigify your data

```
data: JSON.stringify({ LevelNameAddLevel: $('#LevelNameAddLevel').val() }),
```

Answer (score 0):

you send the parameter(data) to web method  then why not received the parameter(data).

i think this is the problem so can u change your lines

```
Public Shared Function CreateUserLevel(LevelNameAddLevel As String) As String
    Return "true"
End Function
```