# Get null data when pass parameter in query string in $.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I use $.ajax for send data in to Sql,
when I pass parameter in query string, I get null in data value,

```
function refreshTime(options) {
        $.ajaxService({
            url: 'http://localhost:1549/Store/Pages/services.aspx?servicename=change,
            data: { oldpassword: $("#oldpassword").val(), newpassword: $("#newpassword").val() },
            onStartService: function () { $(".failed-message,.success-message").hide(); $("#submitchangepassword,#oldpassword,#newpassword,#confirmpassword").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); },
            onEndService: function () { $("#submitchangepassword,#oldpassword,#newpassword,#confirmpassword").removeAttr('disabled').not("#submitchangepassword").val(""); },
            onResponse: function (response) {
                if (response.result == '1') {
                    $.pushMessage({ message: 'success', messageClass: 'success-message', delay: 6000 });
                }
                else {
                    $.pushMessage({ message:'error ', messageClass: 'failed-message', delay: 8000 });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

*I get null data in services page,*

but when I don't pass parameter I get correct data value,

```
function refreshTime(options) {
        $.ajaxService({
            url: 'http://localhost:1549/Store/Pages/services.aspx,
            data: { oldpassword: $("#oldpassword").val(), newpassword: $("#newpassword").val() },
            onStartService: function () { $(".failed-message,.success-message").hide(); $("#submitchangepassword,#oldpassword,#newpassword,#confirmpassword").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); },
            onEndService: function () { $("#submitchangepassword,#oldpassword,#newpassword,#confirmpassword").removeAttr('disabled').not("#submitchangepassword").val(""); },
            onResponse: function (response) {
                if (response.result == '1') {
                    $.pushMessage({ message: 'success', messageClass: 'success-message', delay: 6000 });
                }
                else {
                    $.pushMessage({ message:'error ', messageClass: 'failed-message', delay: 8000 });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In this case, I dont get null data,

**What is the reason?**

Comment: Try adding `servicename: "change"` to the ajax data component, along with the password values.

Comment: add the content type into your ajax method, like this  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @AndreiV when i do this my query strin is nul in services page

Comment: @VarunPaul,Not make a difference

Comment: Could you post the controller code(i assume it's mvc)? Kinda hard to know whats going on in there without it :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"{ 'oldpassword': '" + $("#oldpassword").val() + "', 'newpassword':'" + $("#newpassword").val() +"'}",
```

or maybe a better way to do it

[jquery ajax method returns null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175452/jquery-ajax-method-returns-null-value?rq=1)